# getting 403 error while trying run GET function on Rest Api to pull data in python

Tags: python, api, request, http-status-code-403

I am getting 403 error while trying run GET function on Rest Api to pull data in python

```
import requests

url = 'https://cdn-api.co-vin.in/api/v2/appointment/sessions/public/calendarByPin?pincode=803101&date=13-05-2021'
ploads = {'pincode':'803101', 'date':'13-05-2021'}
r = requests.get(url, params = ploads)

data = r.text
```

Comment: I think that the problem is with the server. It shows 403 errors when I connect with my web browser

Answer (score 0):

403 means forbidden means the server understands your request but forbid your access. Please check if you have required access to the resource you are trying to access.
Don't confuse this with 401 which happen when you don't have authorization.